# Submit a form using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

First, here is my code :

**routes.php**

```
$router->resource('vips','formController');
```

**formController.php** (im only posting the concerned function)

```
public function store(CreateVipRequest $request, Vip $vip, Pool $pool, Url $url)
{
    $new_vip = $vip->create($request->except(['srv_hostname', 'srv_ip', 'srv_port','url']));
    $pool->fill($request->only(['srv_hostname', 'srv_ip', 'srv_port']));
    $url->fill($request->only(['url']));

     /* Some more inserts on the database...*/

    return redirect()->route('vips.show', [DB::table('vips')->max('id')]);
}
```

My code submits the form, and after some json requests to a distant Api (and some databases insertions) it redirects to the show view.

Now I want to add a second button that submits the form via Ajax.

**Question** : Is there a way to use the same function `store` ? I need it to be able to process both an ajax submit and a normal submit.

Comment: You might like to use form's 'Post' in actions and then submit the forms data after serializing via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Submit form using ajax

```
$("#form-name").submit(function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();  
  var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
  var postData = $(this).serializeArray(); 
  $.ajax({
    url: formURL,
    type: 'POST',
    data: postData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      location.reload();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      var errResponse = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

In your javascript you can do something like this (assuming you're using jquery):

```
// if you're using a form
var data = $('form').serialize();

// if data comes from elsewhere
var data = {foo: 'bar', ...};

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    // Do something if everything went fine
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Do something if something went wrong
  },
});
```

Your controller will catch the data coming from the request as you are already doing.